# Google AI Platform: kernel dying

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ai

I am trying to run a simple Python script for data cleaning in a notebook on Google Cloud AI Platform.

The notebook has 4 CPUs and 15GB RAM. I tried cleaning data chunks of different sizes, from 10GB to 200MB, the issue remains the same: the kernel keeps on dying. I keep on getting the following error message:

File Save Error for GCAM tidy up 1219.ipynb
    Error 504 (Gateway Timeout)!!1  *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}

**504.** That’s an error.

That’s all we know.

Dismiss

The script I am using uses just pandas. I tried to make my code more efficient by collecting garbage and deleting variables no longer needed.

Any idea why this error keeps occuring would be much appreciated!

Comment: No more in the logs of your notebooks?

Comment: what version of AI Platform notebooks are you using? Any special network setup that may be blocking traffic to/from GCP ?